# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP

Tags: c, wpf, wcf

I have this error in my client.
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8099/IService. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'
client config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProgrammService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8099/IService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProgrammService" contract="ServiceReferenceMrChicken.IProgrammService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProgrammService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v14.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeConnection" connectionString="Data Source=den1.mssql7.gear.host;Initial Catalog=mrchikendb;User ID=mrchikendb;Password=Qwer-12" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

server config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="IService.ProgrammService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
        <endpoint address="IService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService.IProgrammService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8099/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="120" maxConcurrentSessions="120"
                             maxConcurrentInstances="120" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v14.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeConnection" connectionString="Data Source=den1.mssql7.gear.host;Initial Catalog=mrchikendb;User ID=mrchikendb;Password=Qwer-12" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\TracesServ_ce.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

code where i gave my exception

```
ServiceReferenceMrChicken.ProgrammServiceClient client = new ServiceReferenceMrChicken.ProgrammServiceClient();
            var users = client.GetUsers();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
```

code where i gave my exception

```
ServiceReferenceMrChicken.ProgrammServiceClient client = new ServiceReferenceMrChicken.ProgrammServiceClient();
            var users = client.GetUsers();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might something amiss during the process of hosting the service your configuration seems to me. You could verify it whether it was be hosted properly by accessing the WSDL of the service.

```
http://x.x.x.x:8009/service1.svc?wsdl
```

Generally, the service endpoint address is provided by the IIS site bindings instead of the base address of the service configuration file, since the WCF service is also hosted as a website by IIS.
So the following code snippets are unnecessary.

```
   <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8099/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
```

Meanwhile, we should provide a http base address in the IIS site binding module.
[image]
Then the service address will be http://x.x.x.x:9001/service1.svc, we could type the service base address to consume it on client side with using Add service reference wizard.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: If the reply is useful, please mark it useful so that whoever encounters a similar problem is willing to read it.